# How to set the text position in video using CATextLayer in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, cocos2d-iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am setting the text using CATextLayer in a video using AVMutableComposition and the text is being displayed but I am not able to set its position on screen ... using this code the text is being displayed but it gets displayed on left side of the screen and gets cut by half...

Is there any one to help me to sort out this problem.I really got struck here and not able to find the solution ..pls help me out

Code i used is ...

AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

```
[compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipVideoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

[compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:[[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] preferredTransform]];

CGSize videoSize = [clipVideoTrack naturalSize];


UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrClipArt objectAtIndex:selectedClipArt.tag-200]];//<=======================code to set the Image using CALayer
CALayer *aLayer = [CALayer layer];
aLayer.contents = (id)myImage.CGImage;
aLayer.frame = CGRectMake(selectedClipArt.frame.origin.x-imgMovieThumbnail.frame.origin.x, selectedClipArt.frame.origin.y-imgMovieThumbnail.frame.origin.y, 400, 400);
aLayer.opacity = 1.0;
CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
[parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:aLayer];

CATextLayer *titleLayer = [CATextLayer layer];//<========code to set the text
titleLayer.string = txtIntro.text;
titleLayer.font = (__bridge CFTypeRef)(txtFont.text);
titleLayer.fontSize = 100;
//?? titleLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
titleLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
titleLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(400,0, 600, videoSize.height/2); //You may need to adjust this for proper display
```

//    titleLayer.frame=CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 30);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:titleLayer];

Comment: can you please suggest me How can you solve this issue ?

Comment: please see my question on this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31780060/how-to-set-catextlayer-in-video-according-to-frame

Comment: Please check the answer given below and try to set the position of it using CGPointMake.

Comment: thanks for your reply, Solved the issue.

Comment: Did you set the position or bounds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the position of the titleLayer.

```
titleLayer.position = CGPointMake (100,100);
```

And the titleLayer.frame did work for me.